# TSQL: How to rename table name London into t_London and keep untouched p_London in proceure body

Tags: sql, t-sql, procedure

I have 50 procedures in SQL Server which updates 50 tables.

Example:
procedure name = "p_London"
table name in procedure body = "London"

I want to add prefix "t_" to all the Tables and keep untouched procedure names.
Simple renaming renames procedure names also into p_t_London.

Is there in TSQL some method to rename only table names in procedure body?

Thank you.

Comment: Generally, using any kind of object prefix on object names in SQL is redundant, due to the fact that where objects appear within the larger statement necessarily determines the type of object (except for views and tables which *should* be treated interchangably anyway)

Comment: Probably a bad idea to prefix like that, it's really annoying. You could find/replace " tablename" with a space, then also ".tablename" with a dot

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, Charlieface, thank you for your comments. Actually, these tables are related to one big process and I want to add prefix to distinct them from another tables in the database.